# Next JS on vercel cannot find module in case of a component file

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

It's literally driving me crazy, it works OK on local computer but shows this error when I deploy on vercel
[image: Error]

I created a components folder with separate component folders in it and an index file to export all the components. The head folder (with index.tsx and other files instead) exists and I have exported the component from it but it still gives the error as shown in the image.

Here is the folder structure of the components folder.
[image: Folder structure]

How can I get it working on vercel?

Comment: Are you sure the folder name is `head` and not `Head`? The import path must be an exact match of the folder/file path.

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, the name of the folder is 'head'

Answer (score 0):

It is a casing problem.

Do `git config core.ignorecase false` which will then show files with changed cases for you to re-commit

Also check Vercel [How to Resolve](https://vercel.com/guides/how-do-i-resolve-a-module-not-found-error)!

What finally worked for me

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add --all .
git commit -a -m "Versioning untracked files"
git push origin main
```